# How to unindent a bullet when the usual ways won't work in ms word 10

Tags: windows-10

Im bulleting directions and doing indented bullets as well. I un-bulleted the last indented bullet completely but changed my mind and bulleted the sentence i had just written. It skipped where the main bullets start and put it where the indented bullets start but i don't want it there.  So i hit the left arrow button in paragraphs, nothing. I tried shift tab, and tab backspace, and tab double space bar, and some others i don't remember now.  It won't budge.  Any suggestions? Thnx

Comment: If you have a different bullet somewhere else in the doc formatted/indented  the way you like then use the Format painter and copy the formatting from there to the misbehaving bullet.